# Why can't my base class pointer variable access functions from the derived class?

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
class Polygon {
  protected:
    int width, height;
  public:
    void set_values (int a, int b)
      { width=a; height=b; }
};

class Rectangle: public Polygon {
  public:
    int area()
      { return width*height; }
};

int main () {
  Rectangle rect;
  Polygon * ppoly1 = &rect;
  ppoly1->set_values (4,5);
  cout << rect.area() << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

In above example, what does **ppoly1** points to and how is this pointer not able to access **rectangle** class's function?

**WHY ppoly1->area() is an error**

Thanks!

Comment: Because you can only access base class methods via a base class pointer.

Comment: because Polygon has no function named area.

Answer (score 6):

The expression `ppoly1->area()` is an error because `ppoly1` is typed to `Polygon` which has no `area` method declared.  When C++ tries to evaluate this member it essentially starts at `Polygon` sees no member named `area` and hence issues an error

It sounds like you want to give the `Polygon` type the notion of an `area` method without an implementation (forcing the derived types to provide one).  If that is the case then you should declare an un-implemented virtual method in `Polygon`

```
class Polygon { 
  ...
  virtual ~Polygon() { } 
  virtual int area() = 0;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Base classes know nothing about their derived classes. When a base class is being defined there is no yet any derived class.

Variable ppoly1 is of the type Polygon *. Class Polygon has no method area so the compiler issues the error.

If you want to use a common interface for derived classes you should declare it in the base class. For example

```
class Polygon {
  protected:
    int width, height;
  public:
    void set_values (int a, int b)
      { width=a; height=b; }
    virtual int area() const = 0;
    virtual ~Polygon(){}
};

class Rectangle: public Polygon {
  public:
    int area() const
      { return width*height; }
};

int main () {
  Rectangle rect;
  Polygon * ppoly1 = &rect;
  ppoly1->set_values (4,5);
  cout << rect.area() << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ppoly1` is a Polygon pointer. The fact that the pointer points to a Rectangle object does not enable it to call Rectangle functions; the type is still `Polygon*`. To enable it to call Rectangle functions you need to either make it a Rectangle pointer, or implement a virtual method in your Polygon class,

e.g.

```
virtual int area() const;
```

This means that when a Polygon object has `area()` called on it, it will go looking for the most derived instance of `area()`. On `ppoly1` this will be `Rectangle->area()`. You can keep your `Rectangle` code the same as before.

Wikipedia on virtual functions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function